# How to set On Item Click listener in a recycler view and send the data coming from JSON in one activity to other?

Tags: android, json

I am able to fetch the data coming from JSON and displayed them in a recycler view, I am getting problem while sending JSON object from this activity mentioned below to other activity using Intent while clicking on the list.

This is my main activity.

```
public class Category extends AppCompatActivity {
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private String android_version_names[]={};
    private String id[]={};

    private String android_image_urls[]={};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.category);
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
        initViews();
    }

    protected void initViews(){
         RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MyItemDecorator(this));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        final ArrayList<CategoryVersions> androidVersions = prepareData();
        DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),androidVersions);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.SetOnItemClickListener(new DataAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                //Snackbar.make(mView, "Item id: "+position+" Product id"+prod.get(position).getId(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //String number = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("num");

                Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, Products.class);

                CategoryVersions pp=androidVersions.get(position);
                //byte[] img= pp.getImage();
                intent.putExtra("num", pp.getId());
                Log.e("cat_id", "position:" + position + ",id:" + pp.getId());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    private ArrayList<CategoryVersions> prepareData(){

        ArrayList<CategoryVersions> android_version = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<android_version_names.length;i++){
            CategoryVersions androidVersion = new CategoryVersions();
            androidVersion.setAndroid_version_name(android_version_names[i]);
            androidVersion.setAndroid_image_url(android_image_urls[i]);
            android_version.add(androidVersion);
        }
        return android_version;
    }
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Category.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            List<NameValuePair> prms = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            prms.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "e465bef9-129b-11e9-9713-000c294888b7"));
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("mu url","GET", prms);

            try {
                String type;
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                Log.d("JSON Data: ", jsonobject.toString());
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("data");
                android_version_names = new String[jsonarray.length()];
                android_image_urls = new String[jsonarray.length()];
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    android_version_names[i] = jsonobject.getString("name");
                    android_image_urls[i] = "my url"+jsonobject.getString("image");
                    map.put("name", jsonobject.getString("name"));
                    map.put("image", "my url"+jsonobject.getString("image"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    //arraylist.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            initViews();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my adapter.

```
  public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<CategoryVersions> android_versions;
    private Context context;
    OnItemClickListener clickListener;

    public DataAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<CategoryVersions> android_versions) {
        this.context = context;
        this.android_versions = android_versions;

    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_card, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

        viewHolder.tv_android.setText(android_versions.get(i).getAndroid_version_name());
        Picasso.with(context).load(android_versions.get(i).getAndroid_image_url()).resize(120, 60).into(viewHolder.img_android);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return android_versions.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        TextView tv_android;
        ImageView img_android;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            tv_android = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_android);
            img_android = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.img_android);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            clickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

}
```

This is activity to which I should send the "id" in this activity I should store this id as cat_id.

```
public class Products extends AppCompatActivity {
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private String android_version_names[]={};
    private String part_no[]={};
    String cat_id;
    private String android_image_urls[]={};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.product);
        cat_id=getIntent().getStringExtra("num");
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
        initViews();
    }

    protected void initViews(){
         RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MyItemDecorator(this));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        ArrayList<ProductVersions> androidVersions = prepareData();
        ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(getApplicationContext(),androidVersions);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();


    }



    private ArrayList<ProductVersions> prepareData(){

        ArrayList<ProductVersions> android_version = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<android_version_names.length;i++){
            ProductVersions androidVersion = new ProductVersions();
            androidVersion.setAndroid_version_name(android_version_names[i]);
            androidVersion.setPart_No(part_no[i]);
            androidVersion.setAndroid_image_url(android_image_urls[i]);
            android_version.add(androidVersion);
        }
        return android_version;
    }
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Products.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            List<NameValuePair> prms = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            prms.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "e465bef9-129b-11e9-9713-000c294888b7"));
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address

            jsonobject = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("My URL" + cat_id ,"GET", prms);

            try {
                String type;
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                Log.d("JSON Data: ", jsonobject.toString());
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("data");
                android_version_names = new String[jsonarray.length()];
                part_no = new String[jsonarray.length()];
                android_image_urls = new String[jsonarray.length()];
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    android_version_names[i] = jsonobject.getString("product_name");
                    part_no[i] = jsonobject.getString("partno");
                    android_image_urls[i] = "My URL"+jsonobject.getString("product_image");
                    map.put("product_name", jsonobject.getString("product_name"));
                    map.put("partno", jsonobject.getString("partno"));
                    map.put("product_image", "My URL"+jsonobject.getString("product_image"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    //arraylist.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            initViews();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.
1. setOnItemClickListner

**change**

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener clickListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

public void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.clickListener = (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) itemClickListener;
}
```

**To**

```
private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void setOnItemClickListener(View view, int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    this.mOnItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mOnItemClickListener.setOnItemClickListener(v, position);
        }
    });
}
```

2. send data

Category Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, Products.class);
CategoryVersions pp = androidVersions.get(position);
//byte[] img= pp.getImage();
intent.putExtra("num", pp.getId());
Log.e("cat_id", "position:" + position + ",id:" + pp.getId());
startActivity(intent);
```

Another Products Activty

```
String cat_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("num");
Log.e("cat_id", "cat_id:" + cat_id);
```

**Another way**

```
private ArrayList<CategoryVersions> android_versions;
private Context context;
OnItemClickListener clickListener;
public DataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CategoryVersions> android_versions) {
    this.context = context;
    this.android_versions = android_versions;

}

@Override
public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_card, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    viewHolder.tv_android.setText(android_versions.get(i).getAndroid_version_name());
    Picasso.with(context).load(android_versions.get(i).getAndroid_image_url()).resize(120, 60).into(viewHolder.img_android);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return android_versions.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView tv_android;
    ImageView img_android;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        tv_android = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_android);
        img_android = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_android);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

public void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
}
```

You just remove `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` and add `v.setOnClickListener(this);`

Just change your code to this and work well.

**Edit**

```
public ViewHolder(View v) {
    super(v);

    tv_android = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_android);
    img_android = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_android);
    // add this to your code
    v.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: can you help how to set adapter.SetOnItemClickListener(new DataAdapter.OnItemClickListener() in my main activity

Comment: i had replaced the code as you said but the clicking action is not happening in recycler view.

Comment: i had replaced the code but I am unable to click the grid in recycler view. clicking action is not working?

Comment: @lakshmankumar Sorry to answer you so late,could you edit your code？And I wil check it.

Comment: I had edited the code can you please check it and let me know the error?

Comment: No I could not able to solve it onclick function is not working

Comment: thanks for the code onclick is working but I am getting null object ref in id

Comment: Could you show the code and show where caused it ?@lakshmankumar

Comment: i had forgotten to add  v.setOnClickListener(this);

Answer (score 1):

Actually the best practice with `recyclerView` and `OnClickListener` is to do this way :

In your activity:

```
//Add this line in the onCreate method
//Add more parameters if needed for your adapter
DataAdapter myDataAdapter = new DataAdapter (context, myClickListener);


private View.OnClickListener myClickListener = new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        //Do something...
    }
};
```

And in your adapter

```
private View.OnClickListener myClickListener;
private Context context;

public DataAdapter (Context context, View.OnClickListener myClickListener)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
{

    //Your attributes

    public ViewHolder(View v, View.OnClickListener myClickListener) 
    {
        super(v);
        v.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
    }
}
```

Of course it works for any kind of clickListener.

And since you declare and implement your clickListener in your activity you should not have any problem to launch the other one.

And to send some JSON data in any case you can use `intent.putExtra("myJSONObject", myJsonObject.toString());`

And get it back with: `JSONObject myJSONObject = new JSONObject (getIntent().getString("myJSONObject")`

Hope this help !!

Answer (score 0):

You may implement this approach for click listener in your RecyclerView:

Change two methods in your adapter:
1. ViewHolder class

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            TextView tv_android;
            ImageView img_android;
            // Save your whole view in your ViewHolder
            View view;
            public ViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);
                view = v;
                tv_android = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_android);
                img_android = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.img_android);
            }
}
```

Then onBindView method:

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

            viewHolder.tv_android.setText(android_versions.get(i).getAndroid_version_name());
            Picasso.with(context).load(android_versions.get(i).getAndroid_image_url()).resize(120, 60).into(viewHolder.img_android);
            // Add listener for that view 
            viewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     // Do your stuff here
                }
            });

        }
```

Hope it will help you.